# Mac Crashes Every Time I Try to Run Boot2Docker

Tags: macos, docker, crash-reports, boot2docker

I recently got a new MacBook Pro running OS X 10.10.2, and I installed Boot2Docker 1.5.0 on it. Aside from Chrome, this is the first program I installed on my new machine. However, when I try to run it, the terminal window opens up for a few seconds, saying boot2docker is up, and then my computer restarts automatically.

I tried to uninstall 1.5.0 and install 1.4.1 (as that is what I was using on my last machine), but I encountered the same problem.

The last thing I see before my laptop restarts is the second image, and the error report my computer shows after the restart is the first image here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/okbx3.png

Has anyone every had this problem before, or know how I can address it? Thanks!

Comment: I think this belongs at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/), not StackOverflow. Please check the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for seeing what should be asked here and what shouldn't be asked here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a specific programming problem, instead an Apple product service and belongs on [apple.SE].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Try [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com), but be sure to read their guidelines before asking there.

Comment: I will ask the question at Ask Different. Thanks!

Comment: If you want a screen grab on your Mac, press  `Cmd+Shift+4` and then draw a box around whatever you want.

Comment: Did you install `boot2docker` using `homebrew`, i.e. `brew install boot2docker` ? It is the easiest and most reliable way on a Mac.

Comment: 1.4 helped me instead of 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Boot2Docker, have you considered making a linux virtual machine on your mac? Then you would just run docker on the virtual machine. 
This fixed all of the problems I had with boot2docker.

The point of boot2docker is to enable docker to run on your mac. If you use a linux VM you will no longer need boot2docker.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm going to be doing this from now on, as I have had some other minor problems with boot2docker before.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question in AskDifferent as well, and it turns out there was a problem with OS X Security Update 2015-003 and boot2docker/virtualbox, as per this link: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/800

Updating my version of VirtualBox remedied the situation.